# ElasticSearch: How to sync a property of a relation (using a pivot table)?

Tags: php, laravel, elasticsearch

I have got the following main model:

Record mapping:

```
Map::create($this->getModelType(), function (Blueprint $map) {
            $map->integer('id');
            $map->string('some_id');
            $map->string('original_title');
            $map->string('first_release_year');
            $map->date('created_at')->format('yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss');
            $map->date('updated_at')->format('yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss');

            $map->nested('contributors', function (Blueprint $map) {
                $map->integer('id');
                $map->string('name');
            });
```

and in my Contributor model:
`protected $touches = ['records'];`

Running my unit tests, I have got the following logic:

- Create 2 entities of the `Record` model
- Create 2 entities of the `Contributor` model
- Update their *pivot* table like this:

  $recordOne->contributors()->attach([
                      $contributorOne->id => ['ranking' => 1],
                      $contributorTwo->id => ['ranking' => 2],
              ]
  );

Then I see my new Record in ES but I don't see the `contributors` property updated and therefore in sync with my DB.

What could be the issue here?